# How to remove trailing character(s) from a string

Tags: java, android, string

I have a file which contains a data structure.  The data is stored as bytes.  I want to display a data (name of person) to screen.  Size of the name is about 12 characters long.  But data may be less than or equal to 12 characters.  I converted the byte array to string and display data. when tried to display data using system.out.println method, it shows data plus unwanted characters.  How to show only wanted data.

i tried with below code

```
// here Name is a byte array
title = new String( Name );
System.out.println("Title = " + title);
```

output i received is

```
    Title = area1����������
```

i want only 'area1'.   please provide a solution to resolve it

Comment: title = new String( Name ).trim();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Title = area1����������".replaceAll("([^A-Za-z0-9 ])", ""));
```

give : `Title  area1`, you can also add `.replaceAll("\ \ "," "));` or tune the regex as you like

Comment: little doubt, i want not suppress '-', '_', '.', '/' is it possible ?

Comment: @harekrishna - Naturally : you concatenate those symbols after the ' '(blank) and before the ']' in the regex : **"([^A-Za-z0-9 -_./])"**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
String decoded = new String(Name, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Also You can try , UTF-16LE Or UTF-16BE

Answer (score 2):

```
    String title = new String( Name ,"UTF-8" );
    System.out.println("Title = " + title);
```

Answer (score 0):

from [How to determine whether a character is a letter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93976/how-to-determine-whether-a-character-is-a-letter-in-java)

```
string.matches("\\p{L}"); // Unicode letter
string.matches("\\p{Lu}"); // Unicode upper-case letter
```

You can also do this with Character class:

```
Character.isLetter(character);
```

but that is less convenient if you need to check more than one letter.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `StringBuilder` class, build up the string by appending each character that is read from input file stream, until the end of file is reached. Once end of file is reached, then immediately return back the string via the `toString()` method of the `StringBuilder` class.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");//
int c = 0;
while ((c = isr.read()) != -1) {
    sb.append((char) c);
}
String fixedString = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

find the updated code here:

```
        // here Name is a byte array
    String title = new String( "area1����������");
    System.out.println("Title = " + title);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(title);
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++)
    {
        if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(sb.charAt(i)))
        {
            sb2.append(sb.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    title = sb2.toString();
    System.out.println("Title = " + title);
```