# why this regex is not working on java 7?

Tags: java, regex, java-7, java-6

As per answer from [How to determine whether a character is a letter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93976/how-to-determine-whether-a-character-is-a-letter-in-java) i was using 
below code snippet to match if string contains unicode letter or not in the begining. It was working great on java 6 where unicode character 
\u0374 was not treated as unicode lettter

```
 boolean test = "\u0374100".matches("[\\p{L}].*");; returns true on java 7 whereas it return false java 6.
```

Has there been any change in java 7 regarding this perspective ?  If yes how to make java 6 things working on java 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Fileformat.Info: Unicode Character 'GREEK NUMERAL SIGN' (U+0374)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0374/index.htm), the category is "**Letter**, Modifier [Lm]". It also says that the result for `Character.isLetter()` is **Yes**.

Now contrast this with [Unicode Character 'GREEK LOWER NUMERAL SIGN' (U+0375)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0375/index.htm) which has category "**Symbol**, Modifier [Sk]". According to the page the result for `Character.isLetter()` is **No**.

Java 7 uses Unicode 6.0.0 according to the [Character javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and  [Internationalization Enhancements in Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.7.html), while Java 6 uses Unicode 4.0 (see the [Character javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and [Java Language Specification 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html) (which applies to both Java 5 and 6)).

The reason is that unicode now defines U+0374 as a "Letter, Modifier". Looking at the unicode database for [Unicode 4.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/4.0-Update/UnicodeData-4.0.0.txt) and [Unicode 6.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) it is clear the definition changed from **Sk** to **Lm**:

Version 4.0:

> 0374;GREEK NUMERAL SIGN;**Sk**;0;ON;02B9;;;;N;GREEK UPPER NUMERAL SIGN;Dexia keraia;;;

Version 6.0.0:

> 0374;GREEK NUMERAL SIGN;**Lm**;0;ON;02B9;;;;N;GREEK UPPER NUMERAL SIGN;;;;

In other words: Your regex is working correctly, it is just that the character definition has changed so it is now considered to be a letter, not a symbol.

Comment: Can i confirm "Either this was different in the unicode version used by Java 6, or Oracle changed how Character.isLetter() responds for category "Letter, Modifier [Lm]"." in release doc for java 7? It oracle has changed the behaviour it should be somewhere in doc. Right?

Comment: I believe they changed unicode version, but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: Java 6 uses Unicode Standard version 4 while 7 uses version 6. It's documented in the Character class javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Comment: @PopoFibo I found it; I had missed it while glancing at the doc.

Comment: @user3198603 I removed my claim that it might be how "Letter, Modifier" is handled, as the Javadoc of version 6 and 7 both claim that that category is considered a letter.

Comment: @user3198603 I have added a reference to the UCD that shows the definition has been changed between 4.0 and 6.0.0

Comment: Thanks mark Rotteveel. One more thing when i write character "\u0374100". I am not gett thru java program on text file it writes the character ` in text file but i copy same wriiten character and copy it in a new tab, it displays ?

Comment: @user3198603 Please accept my answer :). The second part of your comment sounds like another question in itself. It could have all kinds of causes, including the default character set of a new file in your text editor. BTW: `\u0374100` is not 1 character, but 4 (U+0374 and 100)